# Why element is not showing onClick?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to figure out what I am selecting incorrectly. I'm trying to click element one and show sub elements.

```js
function main(){
  $('.option-button').hide();
  $('.nav-buttons').on('click',function(){
    $('option-button').next().toggle();
  });
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
.container {
  overflow:auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-style: double;
  background-color: #1e1e15;
}

.header {
  font-family: "Ailerons";
  font-size: 125px;
  text-align:center;
  width: auto;
}
h4{
  margin:auto;
  color: blue;
}

.nav-bar{
  width: 75.5%;
  border-style: double;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav-buttons {
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
}
.option-button{
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}
li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    font-family: monospace;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 44.3;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-style: dotted;
}

.navigation-pictures {
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  margin:auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  border-style: double;
  border-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<hmtl>
  <head>
    <title>My Home Page!</title>
    <link href = "style.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet"/>
  </head>
    <body>
      <div class = "container">
          <div class = "header">
            <img src = "images/iceland.png" alt = "Downtown" height="30%" width="55%"/>
          </div>
          <div class = "nav-bar">
            <ul class = "nav-buttons">
              <li>Element 1</li>
                <ul class ="option-button">
                  <li>Element 1 Sub Element 1</li>
                  <li>Element 1 Sub Element 2</li>
                </ul>
              <li>Element 2</li>
              <li>Element 3</li>
              <li>Element 4</li>
              <li>Element 5</li>
              <li style="float:right">Element 6</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div  class = "navigation-pictures">
            <img src = "images/city1.jpg" alt = "Downtown" height="100%" width="100%"/>
         </div>
         <div  class = "navigation-pictures">
           <img src = "images/lighthouse1.jpg" alt = "Lighthouse" height="100%" width="100%"/>
        </div>
        <div  class = "navigation-pictures">
          <img src = "images/moutains.jpg" alt = "Moutains" height="100%" width="100%"/>
       </div>
    </div>
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js'></script>
    <script src='main.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A **minimal** demo would be preferred. We dont need the *whole page*

Comment: If you click run demo it shows you exactly what is happening. When element 1 is clicked nothing takes place, but what is expected is the other sub elements to show.

Comment: So reduce the demo to just the section that is a problem. Most of the code you have provided is irrelevant.

Comment: Please read the guidelines for how to create a minimal but to the point solution http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You guys are so up tight is blows my mind. Just don't answer the question. Just leave the question if you don't wanna diagnose it.

Comment: @Jengo, The people you're crying about didn't answer, they're commenting. They're attempting to improve the question and the code, which will help focus the answers. That focused code will help to more easily identify and comprehend what is going on (for newbies and pros alike) when a user identifies your issue as their issue. With extraneous code the user might focus on the wrong parts, get confused or think all of it is necessary to solve their problem, when it isn't. Clear and concise helps everyone. FYI, you can't **bold** your code.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, please tag your question as such. Some people have their filters set to exclude jQuery questions. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want some of:

Put ul in li element and not external.
Take click event on li element and not ul.

```
<ul class = "nav-buttons">
              <li>Element 1<ul class ="option-button">
                  <li>Element 1 Sub Element 1</li>
                  <li>Element 1 Sub Element 2</li>
                </ul>
</li>


$('.nav-buttons li').on('click',function(){
    $(this).find("ul").toggle();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Very close, just need to look at children elements

The method you were using to find the child `option-button` was close but not quite right. In this working version of the code I changed the click function to use the `.children` method to find it's child that has the class `option-button`

### Working Example:

```js
function main(){

  $('.option-button').hide();
  $('.nav-buttons').on('click',function(){

    $(this).children('.option-button').toggle();

  });
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
.container {
  overflow:auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-style: double;
  background-color: #1e1e15;
}

.header {
  font-family: "Ailerons";
  font-size: 125px;
  text-align:center;
  width: auto;
}
h4{
  margin:auto;
  color: blue;
}

.nav-bar{
  width: 75.5%;
  border-style: double;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-buttons {
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
}

.option-button{
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}

li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    font-family: monospace;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 44.3;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-style: dotted;
}

.navigation-pictures {
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  margin:auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  border-style: double;
  border-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<hmtl>
  <head>
    <title>My Home Page!</title>
    <link href = "style.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet"/>
  </head>
    <body>
      <div class = "container">
          <div class = "header">
            <img src = "images/iceland.png" alt = "Downtown" height="30%" width="55%"/>
          </div>
          <div class = "nav-bar">
            <ul class = "nav-buttons">
              <li>Element 1</li>
                <ul class ="option-button">
                  <li>Element 1 Sub Element 1</li>
                  <li>Element 1 Sub Element 2</li>
                </ul>
              <li>Element 2</li>
              <li>Element 3</li>
              <li>Element 4</li>
              <li>Element 5</li>
              <li style="float:right">Element 6</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div  class = "navigation-pictures">
            <img src = "images/city1.jpg" alt = "Downtown" height="100%" width="100%"/>
         </div>
         <div  class = "navigation-pictures">
           <img src = "images/lighthouse1.jpg" alt = "Lighthouse" height="100%" width="100%"/>
        </div>
        <div  class = "navigation-pictures">
          <img src = "images/moutains.jpg" alt = "Moutains" height="100%" width="100%"/>
       </div>
    </div>
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js'></script>
    <script src='main.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, Can you explain to me why next() was not working?

Comment: No problem, so there were a few reasons. 

1) you were referencing `option-button` wrong
2) Next is used to find an element's next sibling. So what jquery would do is find the `option-button` element and then look to see if there is an element after it and return that. In this case there was no element after `option-button` in your `li` tag.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/next/

For more information on how it works. Would you like me to include this information in the answer?

Comment: Wont I run into the issue of showing all children of any of the elements (1,2,3,4,5,6)? If it has no children nothing should happen.

Comment: Yes, you could. In that even you could use the `eql` `first` or any other jquery filtering method to help. There are allot of ways to tackle this problem. Sorry if my answer is not comprehensive enough.